# Change Twilio From number with custom number

Tags: php, twilio-api

I'm trying to change the `From` number while sending message using Twilio send message API using this code.

I'm able to send message but I'm getting message from code like `+59039***` instead number I defined in `"from" => '++9199987****'`.

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong or missing something.

```php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
 
use Twilio\Rest\Client; 

$sid = "AC************"; 
$token = "************"; 

$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);

try {
    $message = $client->messages->create('+91799063****',
        array("from" => '++9199987****',"body" => "This test message"));
} catch (Exception  $e) {
    echo $e->getCode() . ' : ' . $e->getMessage()."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Is the +91 number a number you purchased in the twilio console? Also, why are there two plus ++ before the number?

Comment: Adding on to @IObert's comment, afaik you can only send messages using Twilio-purchased phone numbers and phone numbers need to be in E.164 format (https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164).